# Log/Keep track which Rails partials & views are used in its render sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am looking for a way to keep track (log) which views and/or partials are used for the rendering sequence in Rails.

My objective is to dynamically compose a stylesheet, comprised of a view's (or partial's) configured stylesheet, with uniqueness. Then once I know which partials/views are used, I can create a stylesheet unique to that request.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to log partials by subscribing to the appropriate active support notification. The rails guides has a list of the built in [action view instruments](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html#action-view).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gem: [view_source_map](https://github.com/r7kamura/view_source_map)